# Should I add a parent tag if I already use the child one?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, etiquette

For example: when I already added the [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) tag, should I add the [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag as well?

Comment: @Shog9 I’m not sure that [meta] is relevant tag here.

Comment: Answer is different on every site, so Shog's tag edit is correct.

Comment: @ShadowWizard could you please show a site(s) where the Shog’s answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no real parent / child tags. Sometimes folks fake it with hyphens, but that's often unreliable - the "design" in [responsive-design](/questions/tagged/responsive-design) refers to something very different from what's meant by [design](/questions/tagged/design).

[image: the Hannibal clock w/ "this is my design" caption]

My advice: use as many *applicable* tags as possible given the constraints of tagging; start with the broadest applicable tag (bug, feature-request, discussion, etc.) and the most narrow applicable tag (say, profile-page or triage) and then fill in the gap between them (design, responsive-design, review, audits, etc.)

Comment: Didn't know before that etc. is synonym for support :)

Answer (score 0):

I know when I'm coding to attach to tags, I will normally over code the tags unless it really doesn't make sense too. My recommendation is to use the least amount of tags to get the job done, then test multiple scenarios. Add tags to compensate when you need to tighten up selection.